# Can I make a constructor for a custom annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to make an annotation for different methods and classes to programmatically keep track of all the rules, so I can display them to the user.

I would like the annotation class `Rule` to record all the places that the annotation is used. As a first step, I tried adding a single static counter to the class, here's what the `Rule` annotation looks like:

```
public @interface Rule {
    static int count = 0;
    String name();
    String description(); //Note the parentheses

    public Rule(String name, String description) {
        count++;

        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The way I would use it is like this:

```
public class Airline {
    private String code;

    @Rule(name = "Formatted Code", description = "e.g. Format 'la' as 'LA'")
    public String codeFormatted() {
        return code.toUpperCase();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Rule.count);
    }
}
```

Without the `Rule` public constructor, this compiles using `javac` version 1.8.0_162.

When I add the public constructor (to increment Rule.count), I get compiler errors:

```
javac Rule.java
Rule.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
    public Rule(String name, String description) {
              ^
1 error

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Mar 22 19:58:39
```

What am I missing in my `Rule` constructor?

Or, is this a completely ridiculous idea and I should feel bad? I can't tell, still getting used to annotations.

Comment: An annotation is an interface, it can’t have variables like that. Think of annotations as an improvement on marker interfaces. So don’t beat yourself up about it but it won’t work. You can write code that scans your classes and counts where your annotation is used.

Comment: Thank you @NathanHughes, I'll do that and then answer my own question.

Comment: You should add the answer to this question.

Comment: Legends have it that he never did. @tlehman you should consider doing that(assuming you're still alive) because not everyone on SO reads comments.